# Using AWS JS SDK in Parse Cloud Code 'AWS is undefined'

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to get the AWS JS SDK to work in Parse's Cloud Code. Below is a simple s3 bucket upload function that works in the browser, but not in the cloud code. I have the js sdk file uploaded in the cloud folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("publish", function(request, response){
require("cloud/aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'MYKEY', secretAccessKey: 'MYSECRETKEY'});
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'maggiesotterocms'}});
var params = {Key: 'data.json', Body: 'Hello world!', ContentLanguage:'JSON'};
s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Success"); 
    }
});

});
```

I get this error in parses error logs when trying to run it

> Ran cloud function publish for user USERID with: Input: {"error":{},"success":{}} Result: ReferenceError: AWS is not defined at main.js:4:2

Comment: var AWS = require("cloud/aws-sdk")?

Comment: I tried that and no luck, the var AWS would become undefined and the next error would be 'no method config found in AWS' or something like that

Comment: I found a work around, I wrote a cloud function that would return my AWS keys if I was logged in as a super admin. Then I would run the S3 upload function from my angular app instead. I'm still interested to see if someone knows how to get the AWS SDK working in Parses cloud code

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to run AWS in cloudcode?

Comment: No not yet, I ended up using a different system. But after thinking about it for a while I think the path needs to be var AWS = require('./cloud/aws-sdk'); the ./ tells node to look outside of bower components.